# How can I get Title and Path from Document Library Using SPListItemId in SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have created one SharePoint Hosted App.
Its Url is Like:
https://a.sharepoint.com/
sites/SharePointAddIns/CreateZip19/Pages/
Default.aspx?
SPHostUrl=
SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=0&
SPProductNumber=16%2E0%2E5806%2E1207&
SPAppWebUrl=2FCreateZip19&
SPListItemId=11,14&
SPListId={33C66D4B-48C2-4A5D-98BF-4D82FEB5CE0D}

> I get SPListItemId and  SPListId in App.Js

```
    var clientContext, hostweburl, parentContext, parentWeb, selectedItems, itemIds, listId;
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlKeyValue("SPHostUrl"));
listId = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlKeyValue("SPListId"));
itemIds = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlKeyValue("SPListItemId")).split(',');
```

Now Question is :
How can I get My document Title name and Url using listId and ItemIds
I have tried this.

```
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(Listitemid);
alert(oList);
oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemid);
var file = oListItem.get_file();
alert(file);
var filename = file.get_name();
alert(filename);
```

But I didnot get file name.

How can I get filename of all selected file using SPListitemId and SPListId ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint Hosted App to get Information of File and its path we can use REST API. I Used Rest call for it.

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
var listid = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlKeyValue("SPListId")).slice(1, -1);
var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlKeyValue("SPHostUrl"));
var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlKeyValue("SPAppWebUrl"));
var itemIds = decodeURIComponent(GetUrlKeyValue("SPListItemId")).split(',');
```

Pass ListItemId to your function

```
function getListVersioningInfo(itemIdd) {

    $.ajax({

        url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists('"+listid+"')/items(" + itemIdd + ")?$select=*&$expand=File",


        method: "GET",
        async: false,

        headers: {

            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"

        },

        success: function (data) {

            var fileName = data.d.File.Name;
            var filePath = data.d.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
            filePathArray.push(filePath);
            console.log(filePath);


        },

        error: function (data) {

            console.log(data)

        }

    });

}
```

Using this Rest Call you will get FileName and FilePath